# Naming a predicate: "precondition" or "precondition_is_met"?

Tags: python, naming, api-design, naming-standards

In my web app framework, each page can have a precondition that needs to be satisfied before it can be displayed to the user. For example, if user 1 and user 2 are playing a back-and-forth role-playing game, user 2 needs to wait for user 1 to finish his turn before he can take his turn. Otherwise, the user is displayed a waiting page.

This is implemented with a predicate:

```
def precondition(self):
    return user_1.completed_turn
```

The simplest name for this API is `precondition`, but this leads to code like `if precondition(): ...`, which is not really obvious. Seems to me like it is more accurate to call it `precondition_is_met()`, but not sure about that either.

Is there a best practice for naming methods like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `precondition` seems to be part of the public API. Therefore, the naming should *primarily* reflect its usage by a consumer of your API. How your code handles that internally is another question all together.

I assume a user will provide a `Page` object that implements this precondition method. In that case, implementing a method `precondition` feels much more natural, *declarative*, and DWIMmy that the verbose (to the point of being Javaesque) `precondition_is_met`. Notice that the *method* is this precondition, and *invoking* it determines whether it was met.

If I am mistaken and the function is solely used in your internals, the longer name seems to be justified, although you could perhaps elide the `is` and use `precondition_met` or `precondition_fulfilled`.

Comment: To compare and contrast.  C# naming convention suggests to prefix the name of a Boolean predicate with `Is`, `Can`, `Has`.  [I find such convention useful.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev which is definitely a good idea. Five years after writing this answer, I probably wouldn't write it again but instead focus on whether that "precondition" might have a better name, e.g. `page.is_available()`.